# electron - node.js - ng : file path\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: node.js, angular, powershell, electron, npm-start

I am trying to compile a project on `Windows 10` in `Visual Studio Code`, my settings are the following:

1) `npm` version `6.12`

2) `Node.js` version `12.13`

3) `Angular CLI: 8.3.19`

The problem I have is as soon as I try to run `ng serve` I receive the following input : `ng : File C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system`. Followed by `For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.`

**What I tried so far**

**1)** I went on the website advised and found that `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` should be the command I have to enter in the shell. Therefore what I did was:

`PS C:\Users\raggi\OneDrive\Desktop\pitalkdashboard> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

But that led to the following error:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell is denied. To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".`

And that is exactly what I did, so in order:

`PS C:\Users\raggi\OneDrive\Desktop\pitalkdashboard> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser`

Below was prompted by the Shell, I only had to insert `RemoteSigned`:

`cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1`

`Supply values for the following parameters:`

`ExecutionPolicy: RemoteSigned`

After that I tried `ng serve` to launch the whole project but received a different error, for which I am putting below a print screen as it is too long:

[image: error]

Don't have any more ideas on going on on this route.

**2)** As advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763146/electron-node-js-fs-readfilesync-requires-admin-privileges-when-electron-is)

I tried to access and run as `administrator` as shown in the print screen below:

[image: admin]

but the only things I visualize on the shell is the following below (however the shell disappears right away and I only had the time to take the print screen)

[image: shell2]

**3)** I dug more into the problem and found some additional insights such as [this one](https://www.technipages.com/fix-access-to-the-registry-key-is-denied) and also [this additional source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system). However the only thing that the post was pointing out was, again, to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` which I tried at point 1) above.

**4)** After a bit more research I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958847/the-term-ng-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/44958882) but unfortunately no useful information I used.

**the code**

Below is what I have in my `package.json` if that is useful:

```
{
  "name": "pi-talk-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "electron": "^7.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.17",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

**EDITS**

After running the -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted as admin the following script opened in `notepad` but I am not sure about its use. I am attaching both print screen and code of the file that opened:

[image: admin]

code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
$basedir=Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

$exe=""
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt "6.0" -or $IsWindows) {
  # Fix case when both the Windows and Linux builds of Node
  # are installed in the same directory
  $exe=".exe"
}
$ret=0
if (Test-Path "$basedir/node$exe") {
  & "$basedir/node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" $args
  $ret=$LASTEXITCODE
} else {
  & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng" $args
  $ret=$LASTEXITCODE
}
exit $ret
```

**EDIT 2**

After running on PowerShell `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` nothing changed. But an error came out. `Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.`
See print screen below

[image: powershell]

I am running out of ideas on how to run this project and on how to solve this `ng serve` problem, any insights or guidance in another direction will be useful to solve this issue.

Comment: This should be related to a recent feature of npm I found to be problematic: <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/470>. Quick and dirty ways to fix are to add `cmd` before the command (eg `cmd ng serve`) or `.cmd` after the command(eg `ng.cmd serve` ) or even just delete all the ps1 files in %appdata%\npm to force powershell to use the cmd file.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You have to set your execution policy to **Unrestricted** not `RemoteSigned`. According to [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6#parameters):

> **RemoteSigned**. Requires that all scripts and configuration files downloaded from the Internet are signed by a trusted publisher. The
>   default execution policy for Windows server computers.

Since 99% of all PowerShell scripts are unsigned, 99% of the time you will not be able to run them under this policy.

1. Open PowerShell as Adminstrator.
2. Run:

.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Hi HAL9256, thanks for reading my question. As explained at point 2) I am not able to access to `ng` script using the `admin` privileges because the shell disappears right away. Is there an additional way to access to the PowerShell as Admin directly on `Visual Studio` embedded Shell?

Comment: (Just to clarify) You only need to run PowerShell as Administrator to set the execution policy to `Unrestricted` **once** to set the policy *globally*. (have you done this?) everything else doesn't need to run as administrator

Comment: The shell will quickly disappear when there is a terminating error (i.e. it runs, errors out and exits). The "best" way is to open a new PowerShell console, navigate to your directory, and run your scripts from there. That way any errors are displayed in the console. After setting the execution policy, what errors are you getting? (please edit the original answer with a section on any new errors)

Comment: I think I am almost there. I am running the shell as admin and went to the folder where file is located: `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm>ls`

Comment: and I see the following files: `ng`  `ng.cmd`  `ng.ps1`  `node_modules`

Comment: Now from here `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm>` how do I set the property for the specific file `ng.ps1` to be `Unrestricted`?

Comment: Ok I just run the following command `C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm>ng.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` and a file opened up. I edited the question under **EDITS**. I am not sure on how to move forward.

Comment: No. Follow the 2 steps in my answer exactly first. Don't do anything else, or run any other script. This is a PowerShell setting. NOT a script setting.

Comment: Once the PowerShell setting is set, then you can navigate to your code and run `ng serve`

Comment: Ok great, last question before I run it: as I open the PowerShell as admin it brings me here `C:\WINDOWS\system32>` , so should I run the execution policy here instead of going to the path of the file?

Comment: Ok I tried but nothing changed. I posted **EDITS 2** on the question. That triggered for an error `Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.` Any idea on that?

Comment: The issue now is not with running `ng serve` the issue is now with your code. i.e. if you build your app with `ng build` you will see the same error. I would guess that the problem is in the `shell` class. You will have to paste the code for `shell.component.ts`

Comment: This solution solved my problem. Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Is there any permanent solution for this? As every time I started my computer and start ng serve in powershell I need to run this "Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted". Before this is not happened to me in my computer actually it is not happened in my colleague's computer as well. As I setup my computer again with windows 10 it start to get this error.

Comment: The current "solution" is to run PowerShell as Administrator to set the global execution policy to `Unrestricted`. If you can't do that, you have to manually set it every time you start PowerShell. (aside) In general this is not really "recommended" as it is turning off one security mechanism, but not setting it for a dev renders `ng` virtually unusable in VS Code. The "real" permanent solution is for npm, et al., to sign all PowerShell scripts with a publicly trusted code signing certificate (don't bypass security, build it with security in mind). This is very hard to do on a public project.

Answer (score 21):

- Issue

I face the same issue and after some research I found simply bypass the restriction and launch your app thru ng server.

- IN TERMINAL you can type below:

PS C:\Users\\\ClientApp> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser

PS C:\Users\\\ClientApp> ng serve

- Rerun your app :

http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 11):

Try using "npx ng" instead of "ng". I get the same permissions error if I try using any "ng" command, including "ng new". Using this npm package runner solves it for me.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9):

Open Powershell as Admin and execute the below command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 8):

Run this command on your project folder

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to run the electron-packager and ran into this problem

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file as mentioned in the error and just delete the ng.ps1 file and it will work fine..

In my case it was nodemon.ps1. I deleted it and server started.

Comment: worked like a charm but can you please share the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 2):

Run below command in powershell.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

If everything is okay , you will see like below screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have Installed angular 12, Even I got the error like below, when I run the application using ng serve

- CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Below is the command I used to resolve the UnauthorizedAccess issue

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when running Angular 12 application. Running the following script by opening Windows PowerShell as administrator mode was solved the issue.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: I faced the above issue while adding material to my angular project
ng add @angular/material
The above command worked for me. I opened power shell in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

adding bin folder path to environmental variable path , will work

Answer (score 0):

Set an environmental variable path, but not working for my case. then used power shell (as administrator mode) run the below line

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

now it is working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Solved in 3 steps***

1. First, open the command prompt and run this command.

**set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser**

2. Now run the second command

**Get-ExecutionPolicy**

3. To view policies, run this command

**Get-ExecutionPolicy -list**

then you will see

Scope ExecutionPolicy

---

MachinePolicy Undefined

UserPolicy Undefined

Process Undefined

CurrentUser RemoteSigned

LocalMachine Undefined

CurrentUser RemoteSigned

LocalMachine Undefined

***now run command ng --version or ng serve***