# How to Unblock-File a single powershell script file

Tags: powershell

I downloaded angular, but running any command, such as ng v or ng new my-app, throw an error: `ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880139/electron-node-js-ng-file-path-ng-ps1-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scri) on the matter on Stackoverflow, and the consensus is just to let to remove any restriction by running this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Since it's an old question, I found this on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file?view=powershell-7.2). I run `Get-Item ng.ps1 | Unblock-File` as suggested by the documentation Yet it still not working [see below screenshot].

[image]

## EDIT

[image]

Comment: `Unblock-File` only causes that your file is no longer seen as an internet file but the execution policies still apply. So, how is the execution policy set ([`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy#:~:text=The%20Get%2DExecutionPolicy%20cmdlet%20shows,script%20isn't%20digitally%20signed.))? Or try: `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\tmp\script.ps1"`

Comment: I run the command you provided. I can't really tell where the content shown in the screenshot is coming from. However, if I try to run `ng v` again, I'm still getting the same: `ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.`

Comment: Try running the command from the `cmd` prompt.

Comment: Seen your edit, which actually means you able to execute scripts like this. So, you just need to put the right commands in `ng.ps1` or directly invoke the commands like: `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ng v`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Powershell+policy+execution)